# Relatively-positioned parent with absolutely-positioned children collapses the later elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="contents">
    <div id="inner">Inner Div</div>
</div> 

<div id="footer">Footer</div>​
```

Applying the following CSS:

```css
#contents {
    position: relative;
}

#inner {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer {
    background-color: red;
}​
```

Problem is that the `#footer` gets collapsed and under the `#contents`. You can check here on jsfiddle also http://jsfiddle.net/MAhmadZ/YkJMH/1/

**Note:** This is just an abstract from a larger page. I have no option but to use `position` properties. I have multiple `div` inside `#contents` all absolutely positions and only 1 will be showed at a time. I can't be sure of the height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have myself come up with the following solution:

```
#footer:before {
    content: '.';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Check it live: http://jsfiddle.net/MAhmadZ/YkJMH/5/

Comment: this is a solution, but not a useful one ;_

Answer (score 5):

Your `#contents` element is empty after `#inner` is taken out of the flow by absolute positioning, so it has zero height and as a result `#footer` collapses under it.

If you give `#contents` a height or some vertical padding, it should prevent `#footer` from sliding underneath your absolutely-positioned element.

Comment: Even if he changes his position parameter to relative it will fix it.

Comment: Actually this is just a short part of the code. I have multiple `div` inside `#contents` all absolutely positions and only 1 will be showed at a time. I can't be sure of the height

Comment: Do you need the footer to be shown immediately underneath whichever `div` is being shown?

Comment: Yes `#footer` should be after `#contents`

Comment: @BoltClock check my own answer.

Comment: why doesn't overflow help here

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it:

```
#contents {
    position: relative;
}

#inner {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
}

#footer {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}​
```

Your problem is `#inner` is positioned absolutely. This makes it invisible to the **STATIC** formatting of HTML layout.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want to achieve, but you can set the footer to use position: fixed and bottom: 0px to keep it at the bottom of the page.